# Feature request: LaTeX preview

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mathjax

I would like to be able to preview my LaTeX when typing my answers and questions!

Comment: Looks like it is `[status-completed]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can now preview $\TeX$ by waiting for <del>5</del> [4 seconds](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/426/feedback-on-mathjax-tex-rendering/444#444).

Comment: See [Geoff's answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/426/feedback-on-mathjax-tex-rendering/444#444) to another question.