# Feedback on MathJax TeX rendering

Tags: discussion, mathjax

**NOTE**: I am locking this question to make sure that people who have problems with the MathJax TeX rendering **post their issue as a new question**, rather than an answer here.

(This question was put up to deal with the immediate feedback when MathJax was first implemented.)

---

Per the most recent edit [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/354/feedback-on-google-charts-for-tex-processing), meta.math.SE and math.SE now have MathJax instead of the previous Google-Charts-based rendering.  Feedback thus far?

Comment: The administrators should talk to Anton, who has successfully implemented mathjax with much fewer errors on the MO faketestsite.

Answer (score 7):

- It looks **much** better.
- <strike>It still doesn't work in the preview when you're editing an entry</strike>per [this answer here on this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/426/feedback-on-mathjax-tex-rendering/444#444) it now works in the preview.
- <strike>It breaks on some things (e.g. `$\binom{n}{r}$` $\binom{n}{r}$)</strike> (looks like the things I saw it breaking on are no longer a problem and with the noUndefined extension, it's much less of an issue anyway)
- <strike>I don't think we have the double-click-to-see-source thing that MO has</strike> right-click to get a menu from which you can get the source
- MathJax needs to be reapplied to the newly-reloaded comments after any of the actions that reload the comments (e.g. clicking "show more comments")

Comment: Occasionally it doesn't work for me the first time I load a page and I have to refresh, but that might be a client-side issue.

Comment: $\sum$ let's see....

Comment: Isaac, that's because it's \sum, not \Sum.  LaTeX is case-sensitive.

Comment: Okay, I just picked on of the ones that produced the error on an answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536/proving-that-1-and-2-d-simple-symmetric-random-walks-return-to-the-origin-with-p).  `\binom{n}{r}` is another example.

Comment: $n\choose r$ is still possible.

Comment: Yes, using `{n \choose r}`, I know (although it now looks like `\binom` works). That point I was trying to make is that there was stuff that people had already put in place, expecting to work, that was not working.

Comment: Clicking the "show more comments" link broke all the math in the comments. I thought this issue had already been fixed.

Comment: The "show more comments" link breaking TeX was a problem on MO for a while, but Anton wrote a fix for it on MO that works for mathjax and jsMath.

Answer (score 6):

The `\binom` thing can be solved by explicitly loading the [AMSmath extension](http://www.mathjax.org/resources/docs/?tex.html#amsmath-and-amssymbol).

I also suggest adding the [noUndefined extension](http://www.mathjax.org/resources/docs/?tex.html#noundefined), so mistyped formulae like

```
\Sum_{k=0}^{1024} k
```

will appear like

$$ \color{red}{\mathrm{\backslash Sum}}_{k=0}^{1024} k $$

instead of the current "`Undefined control sequence \Sum`". This way, at least [the answer quoted by @Issac](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536/proving-that-1-and-2-d-simple-symmetric-random-walks-return-to-the-origin-with-p) is readable before editing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Kenny - I have enabled the AMSmath extension and noUndefined.

Answer (score 6):

You should no longer need a sandbox to test MathJax - just stop typing for around 4 seconds and watch the conversion occur in the preview.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks Geoff! Is it possible for the re-rendering pass to also cover expanded comments?

Comment: You you reduce the waiting period to say 2 secs?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be breaking all over the place. Fixing this is vital otherwise we'll have "broken-windows" all over the place

Answer (score 2):

There's a [bug when editing comments with formulae in it](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/419/editing-a-question-containing-formulae-will-remove-the-formulae) (note it is *not* really [status-completed])

Answer (score 1):

That's very good news to hear. It looks nice, and is a worthwhile investment for the site.

Occasionally, my usual browser (Chrome on Linux) freezes, especially when I try to close a question, and the math does not actually display occasionally. I don't seem to have this problem with Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

My usual browser (Internet Explorer 8) does not display math formulae (in LaTeX) of this site, unlike of a WordPress blog. I changed to Firefox, which displays them properly.

Addendum: Firefox 3.6.8 (Portuguese).

Comment: Please check if http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/597/tex-broken-for-me/601#601 solves the problem.

Comment: @KennyTM: No, unfortunately.

Comment: For the first time using the same Internet Explorer I've written just now an answer that displayed correctely in the pre-view window. However in the Question and Answers view, it does not display properly. I do not find any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good, definitely the way to go forward. No luck in Firefox 4.0 Beta 2 however (I get `[Math Processing Error]`) everywhere.

Comment: @Noldorin: As mentioned by Jeff in [his answer to another meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/305/frequent-page-crashes-in-chrome/387#387), beta browsers are not supported.

Comment: @Kaestur: Would be nice to have an option to turn rendering off though, saying that.

Comment: @Noldorin: You could always just block the math-tex or MathJax scripts. Someone who knows more about Firefox can comment on the details.

Comment: @Kaestur: This is true. Would be nice to have the option still, should be easy to implement.

Comment: Please check if http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/597/tex-broken-for-me/601#601 solves the problem.

Comment: Seems to be working fine in Beta 3. Some layout issues though...

Answer (score 0):

I'm always getting the math processing error in my usual browser, Firefox 3.0.19.  It works all right with Chrome.

Comment: is there any particular reason you're using a browser two versions old? Firefox 3.5 and 3.6 were major releases with lots of big, big bugfixes.

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks, updating firefox solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Works really slowly in Firefox 3.6.11 on MacOS X, perhaps for the reason mentioned [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mathjax/forums/forum/948701/topic/3830450); it just takes ages until it *starts* rendering. In MO there's no delay but it's still a bit slow.

Comment: I'm locking this question because a lot of what's here is too old.  Your answer here is important, but I fear that it will be lost in the noise here.  Please repost this as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to draw attention to the comment written by Kaestur Hakarl:

> > Works for me. Thanks Geoff! Is it possible for the re-rendering pass to also cover expanded comments?

In order to re-render comments, [here](http://www.mathjax.org/resources/docs/?typeset.html) is the appropriate documentation.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/397/tex-formatting-in-other-comments-in-the-same-post-is-lost-when-the-comment-list-i

Comment: I'm locking this question because a lot of what's here is too old.  Your answer here is important, but I fear that it will be lost in the noise here.  Please repost this as a new question.